# Mongoose-Model Restrictions

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, model

I have the following model and I want cartaoCidadao to have exactly 8 numbers. The regex is not allowing lesser than 8 but it is allowing more than 8. What is wrong? I also want password to have at least 8 characters.

```
ar userSchema = new Schema({
  cartaoCidadao: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "cartaoCidadao is a required field"],
    index: true,
    unique: true,
    match: /[0-9]{8}/,
  },
  password: { type: String, required: ["password is a required field"] },
  role: { type: String, enum: ["Admin", "Technical", "User"] },

  estado: { type: String, enum: ["Infetado", "Suspeito", "Não Infetado"] },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{
    cartaoCidadao: {
        //Match exactly 8 digits
        match: /^[0-9]{8}$/,
    }
    password: {
        //Any character, at least 8
        match: /.{8,}/,
        //or At least 8 characters in the list
        match: /^[0-9A-za-z]{8,}$/,
    }
}
```